# I want to check if an element in a list is within a specific range of another element from that list using circle coordinates

Tags: python

I'm looking at at circle and n numbers of points on that circle. I want to check if those elements are on the same semicircle, so within 180 degrees from eachother. How can I check, using the first element in the list, if the other elements are within that same semicircle? I'm using [-180,180) range.

At first, I was originally checking if the elements were positive or negative, but then I realized that I have to use the first element as a starting point instead of 0. Where I really get lost is when checking from the first element, if I check for just plus or minus 180, then that reaches outside of my original range. Also, I don't know how I would use python code to check that.
I can try to explain it in psuedo-code:
if point[1] is within +180 or -180 of point[0] then count++

Comment: What coordinate system is used to define the points? Cartesian? Polar? Something else?

Comment: Unless the points are on exact opposite sides of the circle, they are always within 180 degrees of each other.

Comment: excuse my lack of terms but its using degree coordinates. I'm using (-180,0) to demonstrate below the x-axis and (0,180) to demonstrate above the x-axis. The whole idea is to test if points are on the same semi-circle so I used (-180,180) to represent the two semi-circles. It's not testing if the elements are on which part of the axis though, its testing from the first element given in the list. I hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the points are defined in polar coordinates (in this case, r==constant with just variations in angular position), you can just calculate the angular distance between the desired point and all other points

```
import numpy as np
theta_values = np.array([45, 90, 120, 150, 170, -90, -60, -30])

# How many of these points are on the same semicircle as the point at 45 deg?
theta_distance = 90
num_points = np.count_nonzero(np.abs(theta_values - theta_values[0]) <= theta_distance) - 1

print(num_points)
# Should print 3 in this example
```

You could set up a for loop that does this for each value in `theta_values`, if you wanted to know all of these sums.

This assumes all of your values are between -180 and 180 degrees, you may have to preprocess the data a little to ensure that this is true;